# How to scrape data from an anchor tag, which is inside another anchor tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am scraping data from a dynamic site using python and selenium web driver.

How to scrape the href of an element, which is inside nested anchor tags?

```
<h3 class="">
    <a href="some link/">Ultimate Content Writing</a>
</h3>
```

This site has lots of links with h3 anchor tags of the above kind, which are all to be scraped. I captured all those anchor tags using the code,

`links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")`

then I did,

```
for link in links:
    href = driver.find_element_by_link_text(link.text).get_attribute('href')
```

which contains unwanted actions and slows down my program.

How to fetch the href of each link in more efficient way?

Comment: I'm no expert, but there is a `find_elements_by_css_selector` method so you can probably use something like `links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3>a')` to find all the links contained in h3 headings.

Comment: Can you share examples of what you expect to get and the current output?

Comment: Thank you @pawel, for such a quick response. That helped me solve.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attributes are not within the `<h3>` tags but within the `<a>` tags. So instead of `find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3>a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3/a").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3>a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3/a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The CSS selector did the work. But, using XPATH's cannot be done as it is a dynamic site, the XPath changes for every refresh.